# How to delete related data one to one relationships laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

Terms table:

- term_id
- name
- slug

Term_taxonomy table:

- term_taxonomy_id
- term_id
- description

My Term model:

```
public function TermTaxonomy(){
    return $this->hasOne('TermTaxonomy');
}
```

My TermTaxonomy model:

```
public function Term(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Term');
}
```

I want to delete related data from `Terms` and `Term_taxonomy` Table , as I do so far is:

```
$category = Term::with('TermTaxonomy')->find($id);
// delete related   
$category->TermTaxonomy()->delete();
$category->delete();
```

It works, but is there any best way method to delete related data and how to use it?

Comment: I recommend you use a foreign key constraint with on delete cascade

Comment: then how to use it ? nice to meet you again @lukasgeiter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you use a foreign key constraint make it so on delete, referencing records will be deleted as well.

With Laravels [Schema Builder](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/schema#foreign-keys):

```
$table->foreign('term_id')
      ->references('term_id')->on('terms')
      ->onDelete('cascade');
```

Now every time you delete a `Term` all related `TermTaxonomy` will be deleted.

In case you don't use the Schema Builder: [MySQL reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can also try **Model Event**.

```
class Term extends Eloquent {
  public static function boot()
  {
    parent::boot();

    // Setup event bindings...
    static::deleting(function($term)
    {
      //delete related  
      if($term->TermTaxonomy()->delete()){
         return true;
      }
      return false;
    });
   }
}
```

Add `boot` function in `Term` Model

When you delete `Term` record first call **deleting method**.
if deleting method is return `true` than delete record otherwise not delete.

```
$category = Term::with('TermTaxonomy')->find($id);
$category->delete();
```

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#model-events

Answer (score 0):

I agree that better is to create foreign keys, but if you for some reason don't want to, you can do a small change to your Term model.

at end of class add this:

```
public function delete(){
   $this->TermTaxonomy()->delete();
   return parent::delete();
}
```

so laravel will delete taxonomies when you will call `Term::find($id)->delete();`